# Compilation errors on the TypeScript Definition Files

Tags: angularjs, typescript, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm going to convert my `*.js` files into `*.ts` on my ASP.net MVC5 app (Not an Asp.net Core app). I'm using VS 2015.I have downloaded the TypeScript Definition Files into `Scripts\typings\` folder.Now when I compile the project it gives 100+ errors on `*.d.ts` files.Can you tell me how to get rid of these errors ?

Errors are like this :

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added `tsconfig.jason` to the `Scripts` folder and now no errors :)

**tsconfig.jason**

```
 {
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "typings/angularjs",
    "typings/jquery"
  ]
}
```